# Register a user within asp.net identify

Tags: authentication, azure-mobile-services, user-registration

The authentification process of my app is based on the azure mobile app authentification (facebook).
But in the background I have to register a user account.

**So where is the right spot to register a user inside of azure mobile app application?**
And where can I set some custom claims like `Role`?

Do I have to create a custom AppServiceTokenHandler?
Or are there any better spots?

Answer (score 0):

> So where is the right spot to register a user inside of azure mobile app application? And where can I set some custom claims like Role?

AFAIK, the app service token handler would validate the authentication token and create your `ClaimsPrincipal`, I assumed that it's a simple way for you to adding your custom claims. Here is the source code for [AppServiceTokenHandler.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Authentication/AppServiceTokenHandler.cs), you could refer to it to implement your custom token handler. Additionally, here is a similar blog about how to add custom claims to azure mobile app authentication, you could refer to [here](http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/05/how-to-add-custom-claims-to-azure-mobile-app-authentication/).